# Remove nautilus without breaking gnome Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, nautilus, nemo

I read other questions about this topic, but I cannot find a final solution.

I always had some nautilus issues (it *freezes* very often and I cannot rely on it during my work), So I decided to install nemo and following [this guide](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/02/set-nemo-as-default-file-manager-in.html) I set it up as the default file manager.

However sometimes when I shut off the computer gnome tells me that Nautilus is not responding so I just want to uninstall it..

But it seems that I cannot uninstall it without breaking gnome, indeed typing:

```
apt-get -s remove nautilus
```

I get:

```
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-sushi nautilus nautilus-sendto nautilus-share ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

so I cannot remove it without removing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.. and I think the consequence is gnome breaking..

Some hints?

Comment: Is it not better keep  nautilus, and installs one or more file managers? Maybe this issue could de correct and it woulb de required for other application. I believe you can change the file manager other default for gnome.

Comment: I don't use nautlius anymore.. But even if I don't use it sometimes it starts and it freezes in background..

Comment: Nautilus is a core program in 16.04. Can't uninstall it without breaking system functionality. It's like a stock app in Android. Just live with it and ignore it. Maybe edit startup programs and uncheck it for autostart.

Comment: I know  about these issues @matteo, but nautilus is a core application of gnome/ubuntu and probably others applications would need it eventually. I think it's better you collect some [logs errors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) when nautilus came to  freeze and post them here before uninstall.